# Change value on validate form when I create or edit a block

Tags: 8, forms, blocks

I need change a value to element on form validation.

I have this code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'block_content_MY_BLOCK_form' || $form_id == 'block_content_MY_BLOCK_edit_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_validate';
  }
}
```

I want change the value of field field_test. This field is plain text.

```
function _custom_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setValueForElement($form['field_test'], 'changed');
}
```

But when I saved this block, the field field_test doesn't change its value.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please insert the validate method inside the #element_validate function and then change the element value.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'block_content_MY_BLOCK_form' ||  $form_id =='block_content_MY_BLOCK_edit_form') {
       $form['field_test']['widget'][0]['#element_validate'][] = '_custom_validate';
      }
    }

function _custom_validate(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
  $form_state->setValueForElement($element,['value' => 'See the change']);
}
```

Comment: I went down about 15 different paths from different answers before discovering this answer. No idea why this isn't documented more clearly anywhere. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use setValue function to change textfield value.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'block_content_MY_BLOCK_form' || $form_id == 'block_content_MY_BLOCK_edit_form') {
    $form['#validate'][] = '_custom_validate';
  }
}

function _custom_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->setValue('field_test', 'changed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work, according to the docs for setValueForElement(). I couldn't get it to work that way, either.

There's what eventually worked:

```
$title = t(
  '@user enrolled in @class',
  ['@user' => $userName, '@class' => $classTitle]
);
$formState->setValue('title', [['value'=>(string) $title]]);
```

If the field has other attributes, like a format name for a rich text field, you might have to add the attributes, too:

```
$formState->setValue('field_notes', [['value'=>'Dogs are great!', 'format'=>'skilling']]);
```

Something else that might help. In hook_alter, my code hides the field that will have its value computed. However, the field needs a value to keep Drupal happy:

```
// Hide the title. Compute it from other elements.
$form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden' ;
// Need to give the field a default value, for Drupal's validation code
// to get to the point where a value for the field can be computed. 
$form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'Dogs are the best!';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit off-topic, but related to the question.

How to add a css class to specific element when validating it.

First of all you need to add `#element_validate` to the form element, for example in your `buildForm()` method.
Something like that:

```php
$form['foo'] = [
  // ...
  '#element_validate' => ['::markAsWrongWhenEmpty']
]
```

Then inside your custom validation callback just add desired css class:

```php
public static markAsWrongWhenEmpty(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
  if (empty($element['#value'])) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('foo', 'error_message');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'error';
  }
}
```

Based on the great answer [#5501](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/267441/5501)